# Steal POST data request with PHP code on HTTPS. Is it possible?

Tags: php, security

Is it possible to steal POST request on HTTPS through PHP code?

If website A redirects to Website B, website A POST data with sensitive info like password so it's possible that website B can steal POST request (containing password)from A through malicious Php code?

If website A is vulnerable to Open redirection on login page. When user enter email and password and click on login it redirects to website B containing email password post request, So it is possible that website B can steal the info?

As we can steal IP,COOKIES TOKEN etc through php code it is possible to steal password?

Thanks

Comment: If website A redirected the request to Website B, can it really be considered stealing?

Comment: If you do not trust URL B, why you send your POST to that URL ? And every URL who get the POST data has access to them, using http or https, the https only help protect data on the way of sending.

Comment: If sent over https it would be encrypted, website B would need the key to decrypt.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I think he's refering to the middle-man here, so the redirection is not done willingly

Comment: As we can steal IP,cookies and other info through PHP code, but is it possible to steal password inside POST request.

Comment: None of the data you just mentioned is "stolen", the browser provides it with the request.

Comment: @chris85 "If sent over https it would be encrypted, website B would need the key to decrypt". What do you mean, exactly? if A is posting to B via SSL (HTTPS) then it's B who is providing the SSL certificate to make that possible, so surely it's trivially obvious that B can understand and decrypt the request?

Comment: @ADyson I was thinking this was an XSS injection question at first, so the encryption from A wouldnt be decrypt-able by B. The more information coming in though, the less I understand.

Comment: Means it's not possible?

Comment: If website A is vulnerable to Open redirection on login page. When user enter email and password and click on login it redirects to website B containing email password post request, So it is possible that website B can steal the info?

Comment: @JohnAlex That sounds like exactly what an open redirection attack is designed to achieve, so, since that vulnerability is exploited by people currently, then yes it seems likely that they can steal data. Otherwise, what would be the point of exploiting it?

Comment: @ADyson can u tell me how website B can steal data.

Comment: Ok you can read more about it here: https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/Understanding-and-Discovering-Open-Redirect-Vulnerabilities/ The main risk is phishing attacks. for a POST request, normally the body data does not get transmitted again after a redirect (although for a GET it might depending how badly the code is written). The idea is usually to try and get the user to enter their password again into a fake website, when they thought they had gone to the real one.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=open+redirection+vulnerability&oq=open+redirection+vulnerability&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60l2j0l2.2752j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the packets are encrypted, and website B has the encryption key (for whatever reason) then yes, website B can decrypt the packets sent from website A containing the username and password, and view them in plaintext.

Website B, however, should NOT have the ability to use the decryption key, especially when the site will be handling sensitive information such as passwords (very bad application security practice). So, if you own website B, do not decrypt these packets here.

With regards to your comment about stealing cookies.. Using MITM attacks, it is always possible to get IP addresses, cookies, and other packets containing usernames/passwords. As long as your login is HTTPS, and the decryption key is not available for use in website B then your login info is safe.

**EDIT:**

I just saw your edit regarding open redirection. With this topic, you enter information on the valid website first. You are then redirected to the malicious website due information added to the URL such as this:

Real website:

```
http://www.target.site
```

Real website with redirect to malicious site:

```
http://www.target.site?#redirect=www.fake-target.site
```

If you click on the second link, you will be brought to the valid site (site A). 
If your site does not protect against open redirection, and you type in your credentials, you will be redirected to the malicious site (site B) which will usually look identical to your site (probably without https though and a different url). At this point your information is still safe since it was encrypted when you sent the POST request.

If you now enter in the password on this malicious site, the site admin will be able to steal your information.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may help you out a bit on this query: `a browser responding to a 302 or 301 redirection`. Is it possible? Yes. Is it easy to do? no. You would need access to Site A's server code to rewrite parts of the logic; if I am reading the attached article correctly.

http://windowsitpro.com/virtualization/redirecting-post-requests

Basically, when a browser receives a status code that indicates the request is being redirect, the browser alters the POST payload; unless the status code is 307 (temp moved).

Comment: Hi David. You do know you can edit your answers, right?